# any idea on how to change font color of field value (Text Area) while the user in on VIEW mode only in netsuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

i'm currently doing to change font color of the value upon saving the record of the form but i can't find the best way to do it using netsuite suitescript 2.0

[image]

VIEW MODE
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the below code will help you to get your task done.

```
var inlineHTMLField = context.form.addField({
  id: 'custpage_inline',
  type: 'inlinehtml',
  label: 'Inject Code'
});                         

inlineHTMLField.defaultValue = "<script type='text/javascript'>function change(){ var d = document.getElementById(\'custbody_original_item_fulfill_date_fs_lbl_uir_label\');d.style.fontcolor='#96FFBB'} change();</script>"
```

Comment: should i create a script "Suitelet" to apply this code?, i just want to add it in my client script?, there's other way to apply change font color aside from the above code?

Comment: already change font color using document.getElementById(""). but currently having problem when the form is for view only, no font color was changed after saving the record.

Comment: please see the 2nd picture attached, that's the one that i want to resolve. thanks